Unreadable file as root on NTFS HD
I have an NTFS partition on an HD. This partition contains 6 files which I can't read in any way. I have tried reading them as root, doing chmod, chown and mount -o rw,remount ... nothing worked.
# ls -l
total 1544780
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomas tomas 611063388 Nov 14  2014 TRE_8446.MOV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomas tomas 609181132 Nov 14  2014 TRE_8447.MOV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomas tomas 177475992 Nov 14  2014 TRE_8448.MOV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomas tomas  19260420 Nov 14  2014 TRE_8449.MOV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomas tomas  43750628 Nov 14  2014 TRE_8450.MOV
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomas tomas 121110004 Nov 14  2014 TRE_8452.MOV
# file TRE_8446.MOV
TRE_8446.MOV: ERROR: cannot read `TRE_8446.MOV' (Permission denied)

Any idea why this issue? It's blowing my mind

What are the permissions on the parent directory?

@tink: The fact that the OP can do ls -l successfully suggests that they have all the directory access they could possibly need.

On the other hand, yes, user2543740, if you have a question about permissions, you might as well do ls -la  and show the information for . and ...

Are they "special" in some way? For example, compressed, or in a OneDrive / Google Drive / Dropbox type directory where they appear to be present but actually are not?

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

I suggest opening a second window and running dmesg --human --ctime --follow. My bet is you would see some errors there.

Could this be an issue of the Linux NTFS driver treating root as just-another-user, rather than superuser?

Can you mount read only (ro)? You cannot chown nor chmod NTFS file systems. They normally do not support Linux ownership & permissions. You get defaults based on how you mount the partition. Often issue with NTFS is caused by Windows Fast Startup which sets hibernation flag. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

@tink the same permissions

@ChrisDavies no

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' i dunno but it's weird it looks to me like a bug in NTFS driver

I'm 99% sure you've got a FS corruption. Run chkdsk /f d: (use the proper letter) from Windows.

I have tried and windows does not detect any errors on the disk with ckdsk /f d:

Is the issue still reproducible after running chkdsk? If it is, send an email to ntfs3 AT lists.linux.dev

yes, will do as soon as possible thx
